# Получение частоты из Web Audio Api

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio

Здравствуйте, подскажите, как из метода getFloatFrequencyData в Web Audio APi получить частоту? К выходу подключено, получаю массив следующего вида:

```
[-72.4644546508789, -50.16435241699219, -39.02543640136719, -37.38917541503906, -42.104286193847656, -47.633304595947266, -45.354637145996094, -31.857379913330078, -27.12179946899414, -30.678062438964844, ......]
```

Понятно, что т.к. метод возвращает Float, то и числа с плавающей точкой. Не все элементы массива имеют значение, отличное от нуля. Одним словом, я вывожу массив из  getFloatFrequencyData в консоль, получаю массив. Теперь нужно из этого массива получить частоту в Hz. Изначально предполагал, что ключ элемента массива - частота, а значение - это громкость в дБ, но как громкость может быть отрицательна?

```js
    this.bands = new Float32Array(this.analyser.frequencyBinCount);
this.analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(this.bands)
console.log(this.bands)
```

И на выходе такой массив... Заранее благодарю.
p.s. Пробовал проверять мелодией заведомо известной частоты (440MHz), ничего не добился

Answer (score 1):

Именно про Web Audio Api я не знаю.
Но громкость в децибелах вполне может быть отрицательной величиной, поскольку это логарифмическая величина.

Отрицательные децибелы означают всего лишь, что текущий уровень сигнала меньше некоторого отсчётного.
А, учитывая, что во многих случаях за отсчётный уровень берётся максимальный уровень сигнала в аудиоустройстве, любой реальный сигнал в этих случаях будет иметь отрицательную величину.

Comment: т.е. чем значение по модулю меньше, тем громкость больше?

Comment: Да, если за отсчётную величину брался максимально возможный сигнал (обычно это так). В этом случае 0 - это максимум. А каждые дополнительные -10 обозначают в 10 раз меньший сигнал. Т.е. -30 - это уже в 10^3 (т.е. в 1000) раз меньше максимума.